# Swf file working in IE,Opera, not working in Firefox/Chrome

Tags: flash

i'm having a hard time figuring why my swf file works in IE,Opera and doesn't work in Firefox/Chrome.
I must say that everything works fine(cross-browser) locally through Aptana and Xampp.

I'm embedding the swf using jQuery Flash Plugin.
Here is the link: www.freepokemon.net

You should click on the play now button and then the video should start playing.
Don't worry if it redirects after 10 seconds, it is supposed to be this way.

Do i have to change something on the server(MIME type)?
Please help!

Answer (score 1):

Historically when I embedded movies swf, mov, wmv, depending on the container tags I would have to use the embed tag and the object tag.  In addition I would have to fail back to some alternate file type, like quicktime along with windows media player, etc or i would have to message the user that there is a plugin problem.

The best model for embedding video for the widest ranges of browsers are examples like:

```
<object classid="clsid:02BF25D5-8C17-4B23-BC80-D3488ABDDC6B" codebase="http://www.apple.com/qtactivex/qtplugin.cab" height="256" width="320"> 

<param name="src" value="http://www.yourdomain/clickhere.mov">
<param name="autoplay" value="false">
<param name="target" value="myself">
<param name="controller" value="false">
<param name="href" value="http://www.yourdomain/your-video.mov">
<param name="type" value="video/quicktime" height="256" width="320">

<embed src="clickhere.mov" height="256" width="320" type="video/quicktime" pluginspage="http://www.apple.com/quicktime/download/" controller="false" href="video.mov" target="myself"></embed> 

</object>
```

or

if you are using dreamweaver you can build out your ActiveX Embed or SWF embedding then you can wrap your jQuery treatment around it or use jQuery to populate it.

As a rule of thumb create multiple failback methods in your code and reuse as you need it.

I hope all this is somewhat helpful.